# Double rounded curves in Tikz

Tags: tikz-graphs, tikzmath

I am trying to do a graph with `tikz`, and I would like your help for some details and technicalities. I am trying to do something resembling the following

: [image]

Here are my problems.

1) I am currently drawing the lines, "line-by-line", and do not use any "double line" trick. The problem with that is that I calculate the coordinates on paper and it's pretty hard to have the same orthogonal distance between the lines, due to their different slopes. I mean it's doable of course, but I wanted to know if there is a command that would calculate it automatically.

2) As you can see, it's pretty ugly around the origin and I am not sure what would look nice. Any idea how to make it look nicer ? I am hoping that a method for 1) would solve this too.

3) The point of the graph is not to draw some lines, but to separate the regions delimited by these lines, that's why I chose this method of double lines. Any artistic idea for this goal is also appreciated!

Thank you for your time,

Edit : Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{134,14,156}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{6,138,39}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{12,39,156}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{153,0,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4] 

% Tau-local stuff, w = s/2 
\draw [very thick, color1, rounded corners] (0.4,-6) -- (0.4,0) -- (33,7);
\node [right, color1] at (28,5.2) { $w = \frac{1}{2}s$ };
\node [color1, align=center] at (19,0) { \Large  $\tau\textsf{-local region, corresponds}$ \\ \Large $\textsf{to classical homotopy groups}$ };

% Exotic Motivic, w = 3s/5 + 2
\draw [very thick, color2, rounded corners] (33, 7.4) -- (0,0.4) -- (31,16);
\node [right, color2] at (28,14) { $w = \frac{3}{5}s + 1$ };
\node [color2] at (25,8) {  \Large $\textsf{exotic motivic phenomena}$ };

% Eta-local stuff, w = s
\draw [very thick, color3, rounded corners] (31,16.45) -- (0,0.85) -- (16,16);
\node [right, color3] at (16,15.5) { $w = s$ };
\node [color3] at (18.5,13) { \Large $\eta\textsf{-local region}$  };

% Vanishing region
\draw [very thick, color4, rounded corners] (-0.4,-6) -- (-0.4,1) -- (16,16.6);
\node [color4] at (-2,-3) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (-2,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (5,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };

% grid and axes (drawn at the end so they're on top)
\draw [very thick, ->] (0,-6) -- (0,16);
\node [left= 4pt] at (0,16) { \huge $\textbf{w}$ };
\draw [very thick, ->] (-4,0) -- (33,0);
\node [below=4pt] at (33,0) { \huge $\textbf{s}$ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The axis in gray is definitely a nice detail that I'll keep. The extra space at the origin is also nicer for sure. It seems though the space between the lines is not the same (seems bigger between red and blue), so I guess you did by hand also ? Maybe there is no other way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{134,14,156}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{6,138,39}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{12,39,156}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{153,0,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,line cap=round]

% Tau-local stuff, w = s/2
\draw [very thick, color1, rounded corners] (0.4,-6) -- (0.4,0) -- (33,7);
\node [right, color1] at (28,5.2) { $w = \frac{1}{2}s$ };
\node [color1, align=center] at (19,0) { \Large  $\tau\textsf{-local region, corresponds}$ \\ \Large $\textsf{to classical homotopy groups}$ };

% Exotic Motivic, w = 3s/5 + 2
\draw [very thick, color2, rounded corners=1pt] (33, 7.4) -- (0.4,0.4) -- (0.4,0.8) -- (31.7,16.45);
\node [right, color2] at (28,14) { $w = \frac{3}{5}s + 1$ };
\node [color2] at (25,8) {  \Large $\textsf{exotic motivic phenomena}$ };

% Eta-local stuff, w = s
\draw [very thick, color3, rounded corners=1pt] (31,16.45) -- (0.4,1.25) -- (0.4,1.6) -- (16.6,16.45);
\node [right, color3] at (16,15.5) { $w = s$ };
\node [color3] at (18.5,13) { \Large $\eta\textsf{-local region}$  };

% Vanishing region
\draw [very thick, color4, rounded corners] (-0.4,-6) -- (-0.4,1.4) -- (16,16.45);
\node [color4] at (-2,-3) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (-2,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (5,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };

% grid and axes (drawn at the end so they're on top)
\draw [very thick,gray, ->] (0,-6) -- (0,16.45);
\node [left= 4pt] at (0,16) { \huge $\textbf{w}$ };
\draw [very thick, gray,->] (-4,0) -- (33,0);
\node [below=4pt] at (33,0) { \huge $\textbf{s}$ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an attempt with fill.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{134,14,156}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{6,138,39}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{12,39,156}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{153,0,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,line cap=round]

% Tau-local stuff, w = s/2
\draw [very thick, color1, rounded corners] (0.4,-6) -- (0.4,0) -- (33,7);
\fill [color1!20] (0.4,-6) to[rounded corners] (0.4,0) -- (33,7) -- +(0,-13) -- cycle;
\node [right, color1] at (28,5.2) { $w = \frac{1}{2}s$ };
\node [color1, align=center] at (19,0) { \Large  $\tau\textsf{-local region, corresponds}$ \\ \Large $\textsf{to classical homotopy groups}$ };

% Exotic Motivic, w = 3s/5 + 2
\draw [very thick, color2, rounded corners=1pt] (33, 7.4) -- (0.4,0.4) -- (0.4,0.8) -- (31.7,16.45);
\fill [color2!20] (33, 7.4) to[rounded corners=1pt] (0.4,0.4) to[rounded corners=1pt] (0.4,0.8) -- (31.7,16.45) -- (33,16.45) -- (33,7.4) -- cycle;
\node [right, color2] at (28,14) { $w = \frac{3}{5}s + 1$ };
\node [color2] at (25,8) {  \Large $\textsf{exotic motivic phenomena}$ };

% Eta-local stuff, w = s
\draw [very thick, color3, rounded corners=1pt] (31,16.45) -- (0.4,1.25) -- (0.4,1.6) -- (16.6,16.45);
\fill[color3!20, rounded corners=1pt] (31,16.45) -- (0.4,1.25) -- (0.4,1.6) -- (16.6,16.45) -- cycle;
\node [right, color3] at (16,15.5) { $w = s$ };
\node [color3] at (18.5,13) { \Large $\eta\textsf{-local region}$  };

% Vanishing region
\draw [very thick, color4, rounded corners] (-0.4,-6) -- (-0.4,1.4) -- (16,16.45);
\fill [color4!20] (-4,-6) -- (-0.4,-6) to[ rounded corners] (-0.4,1.4) -- (16,16.45) -| cycle;
\node [color4] at (-2,-3) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (-2,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };
\node [color4] at (5,11) { \scalebox{3}{$0$} };

% grid and axes (drawn at the end so they're on top)
\draw [very thick,gray, ->] (0,-6) -- (0,16.45);
\node [left= 4pt] at (0,16) { \huge $\textbf{w}$ };
\draw [very thick, gray,->] (-4,0) -- (33,0);
\node [below=4pt] at (33,0) { \huge $\textbf{s}$ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an attempt with `double` lines. I am too lazy now to put in colors.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,]
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-0.4cm,-6) rectangle (15,16);
    \draw[very thick,double=white,double distance=0.2cm,rounded corners=2mm] (0,-7) -- (0,2)-- (14,17);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0.25cm,0) rectangle (29,16);
    \draw[very thick,double=white,double distance=0.2cm] (0,0.8) -- (28,17);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0.25cm,-0.3) rectangle (33,8);
    \draw[very thick,double=white,double distance=0.2cm] (0,0) -- (34,7);
  \end{scope}


  % grid and axes (drawn at the end so they're on top)
\draw [very thick,gray!40, ->] (0,-6) -- (0,16.45);
\node [left= 4pt] at (0,16) { \huge $\textbf{w}$ };
\draw [very thick, gray!40,->] (-4,0) -- (33,0);
\node [below=4pt] at (33,0) { \huge $\textbf{s}$ };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that looks good. The filling doesn't look bad either, I'm gonna have some tries and see. I'm gonna wait a day or two to see if people have other ideas and then accept :)

Comment: The last one looks pretty awesome! Let me try to incorporate it

Comment: Although I won't keep any of those in the final project, I accept the answer since it pretty much answers the question. The colors on the last example are not trivial, because in the original example, pair of lines aren't the same color, but it's probably doable without too much trouble.